# frustumM / setLookAtM in OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, frustum

I am playing around with OpenGL on the Android platform using the OpenGL ES 2.0 tutorial as a basis. The code in question is:

```
public void onSurfaceChanged( GL10 unused, int width, int height )
{   GLES20.glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );

    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    Matrix.frustumM( mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1,  9.9999f );

    Matrix.setLookAtM( mVMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f );

    muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation( mProgram, "uMVPMatrix" );
}
```

In particular, the "far" parameter to frustumM. Whenever that parameter is 10 the image (a triangle) does not appear. Any other value is OK. Why?

I have done a fair bit of reading - all to no avail. Even my friend (aka Google) has not been able to help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you calculate your projection matrix you specify the far plane to be at 9.9999f,
which is why an eyeZ value of 10 or larger in the view matrix calculation will result in an empty image. You are looking outside of your frustum.

Please take a look at this article: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I wasn't as clear in my question as I could have been. When the 'far' parameter is, say, 9 or 11 all is OK. The triangle only fails to appear when the parameter is 10. What am I missing?